# How do I insert two landscape pages in to a portrait Word 2010 document but maintain sequential page numbering?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, orientation, page-numbers

I want to insert two landscape pages in to my otherwise portrait Word 2010 document but maintain the sequential page numbering i.e. my final portrait page before the landscape pages is 38, so the first landscape page should be 39 and the second 40, the next page is portrait so should be 41.

Except I can't make it work properly - it's driving me nuts! Please help.

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you try, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: Also, remember to mark this question as answered if it has

Answer (score 4):

**Use section breaks.**

1. Place the cursor at the end of the last line of text of your page 38 portrait page, then go to **Page Layout** tab > **Breaks** > **Section Breaks** > **Next Page**.

   [image]
2. You will then see a section break marker. Now, change the orientation (in your case pages 39-40) to Landscape.

   [image]
3. Then insert another section break at the end of the pages you just changed to landscape orientation, and change the orientation of the succeeding pages (41-up) back to portrait.

   [image]
   This would be the sample output.

Comment: Thanks for the help msPeachy, really apprciate it.  I'd managed to get that far but the page numbering doesn't follow as it should.  I get the first landscape page as page 1, the second as page 2 and then the following portrait page as 1.  Still scratching my head...

Comment: I got it!  Just in case anyone else is struggling with this in Word 2010 then Click footer section of document at offending page; then Insert > Header & Footer > Page Number > Format Page Numbers > and Continue From Previous Section.  Jenny

Comment: How did you add the page numbers? If you did it via Insert tab > Page Number, make sure to check that in the Format Page Numbers dialog, the "continue from previous section is selected".

Comment: The Design tab page numbers and the Insert tab are in fact a bit different - why I couldn't work out what was the trouble.  Now sorted and much less frustrated!  Thanks again